# Which sub-site to ask a question about “GnuCash"

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I want to ask a question about the optimal way to **use** gnu cash (I am not planning to edit the code). I can get it to do what I want, but want to ask for a better workflow for two situations.

When adding an invoice, I want it to auto fill: action=hours, income account=sales, tax=no, unit price=«Customer dependent».

I would also like to auto pay some invoices (some customers pay at time of me doing the work). I would also like to auto fill, which account, each customer pays into.

I may also have other questions. They are all about optimising my work flow, as a user.

Which sub-site should I post it on?

Comment: Depends on the specific of the question. What situation you have?

Comment: I'm confused - how is a question asking for a site recommendation unclear?

Comment: @Makoto since you seem to know if OP asking about some code / code modification for [GnuCash](http://gnucash.org/) or actually using it for day-to-day life as regular user why would not you edit question to clarify?

Comment: I have addressed your concerns, by editing the question.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov:  It never read like a code modification question, it always read like a "how do I use this program" question.  I know *of* GnuCash because it's something you can install as a userland application on most Linux distributions.  The question is perfectly clear:  where do I ask questions like this?  100% assured it's not going to be Stack Overflow but we as a community can at least point them in a better direction.

Answer (score 8):

[Personal Finance and Money](https://money.stackexchange.com) seems like the right place to ask questions about the correct way to use GnuCash. There's even [a tag for it](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gnucash), with almost 200 questions, most of which have answers.

However, note that according to the tag excerpt, " As this is a personal finance site, questions about usage of the software are preferred over technology-related questions.". If your question is more oriented towards technology (e.g., installation or compatibility issues), you may want to consider [Super User](https://superuser.com/) instead.